# Cannot find realm proxy class in 5.1.0

Tags: android, realm

In the earlier release, it has been changed to

```
io.realm.you_package_name_ModelNameRealmProxy
```

but I guess they changed again in the latest release. Anybody know where to find the proxy class?

Comment: I don't *think* that anything's been changed with that. o_o maybe do a clean-rebuild?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Did That countless times but can't resolve it.

Comment: Have you found what the proxy name is? It has to be there somewhere.

Comment: I guess running the application instead of rebuilding it resolved the issue. So strange.

Comment: Gradle sync it is, then